# Core Data migration Add column and keep the data

Tags: swift, core-data, migration

I already have a Core Data implementation on my actuel version of my app, I added some column to the future version, when I uploaded it on the AppStore, I have lost the data. I don't understand because I used the renaming ID to perform the migration:

[image]

Comment: Does your code tell Core Data to migrate the data?

Comment: @TomHarrington No it doesn't